# Linear Algebra question - follow up

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to get more out of this question: [Rank of a matrix when adding new columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492447/linear-algebra-challenge-question)

Again, let $X$ be a matrix of size $m\times n$ with a rank of $r$.

Does this also apply to vertical, now let's call it Z again. where $Z={X\choose Y}$ that has a size of $k\times{n}$ where of course $m<k$.

Do I go the same approach that to prove rank $Z\geq$ rank X?

Any examples that rank $Z$= rank $X$?  And examples that rank $Z>$ rank $X$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know that rank is invariant under transpose?

Comment: Yes, column rank equals row rank. The same examples apply.

Comment: Rank is invariant under transpose? Is there a proof?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_.3D_row_rank).

Comment: If I remember correctly, I think that $\mathrm{rank}(A^\mathrm{T}) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$ is actually an exercise in Artin.

Comment: Ok I just found that after some digging thanks man

Comment: Given the aparently limited experience of OP with rank, I might suggest not trying to understand the proof that rank is invariant under transpose just yet. It is not an easy result, unlike to the question asked here.

Answer (score 0):

If a list of column vectors is linearly independent, then making the columns longer in any way you like will not make them linearly dependent. After all, if some non-trivial linear combination of the longer columns would be zero, then certainly the initial entries of that linear combination would be zero, in other words the same non-trivial linear combination gives zero for the original columns.

Therefore extending the colmns cannot make the (column) rank decrease.